# Frobenius formula for the determinant

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Is there a formula for the determinant of an induced representation, e.g. in the fashion of the Frobenius character formula.

I would hope for something:

> $$ det \; Ind_H^G \rho(g) = (-1)^\alpha \prod\limits_{\gamma, \gamma_1 \in G/H \atop \gamma^{-1}g\gamma_1 \in H} det \rho(\gamma^{-1}g\gamma_1).$$

If you have a reference or a quick proof, that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, yes there is, but it's slightly complicated by the fact that the permutation action of $G$ on the (say right) cosets of $H$ introduces a sign. Also, you have to worry about "non-diagonal" blocks. Hence, if we let $T$ be a complete set of representatives for the right cosets of $H$ in $G,$ then ${\rm det} {\rm Ind}_{H}^{G}(\rho)[g] = \prod_{s,t \in T: sgt^{-1} \in H} {\rm det}(\rho(sgt^{-1}))$ if $\rho(1)$ is even, but is ${\rm sign}_{H}(g)\prod_{s,t \in T :sgt^{-1} \in H} {\rm det}(\rho(sgt^{-1})$ if $\rho(1)$ is odd, where ${\rm sign}_{H}(g)$ denotes the sign of the permutation of the right cosets of $H$ in $G$ induced by right multiplication by $g.$ In the 1970's, T. Yoshida did some work on "character-theoretic transfer", which exploited the determinant of the induced representation, especially when $\rho$ was linear. In some situations, Mackey type formulae for the determinant of the induced representation can simplify calculations.
Later edit: Perhaps a word about the use of Mackey type formulae. It can simplify things to look at the orbits of $\langle g \rangle$ on right cosets of $H$ in $G,$ in other words, to group contributions from the $(H, \langle g \rangle)$-double cosets. The factor ${\rm sign}_{H}(g)$, can be accounted for as above: suppose that there are $k$ of these double cosets, and that $t_1,t_2, \ldots, t_k$ are representatives, where the double coset of $t_i$ consists of $m_i$ right cosets of $H.$ Then the formula for the determinant of ${\rm Ind}_{H}^{G}(\rho)[g]$ may be expressed as ${\rm sign}_{H}(g)^{\rho(1)} \prod_{i=1}^{k} {\rm det}(\rho( t_{i}g^{m_i}t_{i}^{-1})).$

Comment: What does $\rho(1)$ refer to, the dimension of $\rho$? What work of Yoshida is especially helpful? Can one do something similar for the characteristic ppolynomial of $\rho$?

Comment: Yes. $\rho(1)$ denotes the dimension of $\rho.$ I think T. Yoshida's apers are just called"Character-theoretic transfer I and II"- they should be in Math reviews, but I'll check (around 1977-80). As to the characteristic polynomial, it looks possible, but slihtly awkward. Isn't it easier just to use the formula for the induced character to determine the multiplicities of all the eigenvalues of $g$ by looking at $\langle g \rangle.$

Comment: @pm: Try MR0491920 and MR0969691

Comment: The last product runs over H\backslash G/H? Thanks this very helpful.

Comment: @pm: Not quite: it runs over $H \backslash G / \langle g \rangle ,$ as explained in the text.

Comment: Now, I get you your are using that $det \; Ind \rho(g) = det \; Res_{<g>} Ind \rho(g)$, i.e. Mackey's induction restriction method;)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 9):

The answer can be formulated in compact form using the usual transfer map $V_H^G\colon G\to H/H'$ or the (not-so-well-known) construction of *tensor induction*: Namely,

> $$ \det( { \rm Ind}_H^G\; \rho ) 
>                = ( {\rm sign}_{[G:H]})^{\rho(1)} ((\det\rho)\circ V_H^G) 
>                =( { \rm sign }_{ [G:H] })^{\rho(1)} (\det \rho)^{\otimes G}, $$

where ${\rm sign}_{[G:H]}$ is the permutation sign character of $G$ on the cosets of $H$. An exposition of tensor induction and a proof of this formula is contained in Curtis and Reiner, *Methods of Representation Theory I* (see Proposition 13.15). It seems this formula is due to [Gallagher](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02993247) ([MR0185017](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=185017)).
Of course, when evaluating at $g\in G$, this yields the last formula in Geoff Robinson's answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is always convenient to have a additional textbook reference.

Comment: I wonder if this can be an alternate construction of the transfer map. In other words, is there a way to see that assigning to a character $\chi$ of $H$ the character $\mathrm{sign}_{[G:H]}\cdot \det(\mathrm{Ind}_H^G\rho)$ of $G$ is multiplicative?